# Battery voltage 2019 Chevy Silverado 1500

Tags: battery, chevrolet, silverado, voltage

Hello everyone I recently got a new battery and had alternator checked and was good. When driving in the early morning voltage stays at 14 which it should but when parked for a while and u go to work in afternoon the voltage drops down to 12.5 or so. What could I look at to help find problems.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You're just talking about resting battery voltage read at the battery itself? Or are you looking at the battery gauge? Is this with the truck not running?

Answer (score 0):

Generally what happens is when you're driving the vehicle it charges the system as needed between 13.8 and 14 volts when you park the vehicle and get in it generally voltage goes down batteries generally do not sit at 13.8 or 14 volts they generally sit around 12.5 to 1211 volts so for the most part it sounds like it's running like it should or are you having any problems starting or are you losing voltage as you're driving

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).